# Badge Proposal - Going the Extra Mile

Tags: feature-request, badge-request

Very often we find ourselves locked into a comment thread.  We know updates should go in the answer, but we also know that doesn't always work and long comment threads happen.  To address that, Stack Overflow already has a handy feature to take the conversation into a chatroom with one click.

I wonder if we can incentivize that a little more.  Not the behavior of the long comment thread, but the behavior of taking a little more time and effort to help someone who may just be having trouble explaining the problem.

How about a badge for "Going the Extra Mile"?

Steps to receive the badge would be:

- Provide an answer to a question
- Both the asker and the answerer post comments on that answer, and the thread is enough to prompt the "let's take this to chat" functionality
- Make use of the "let's take this to chat" functionality (invoked by either the asker or the answerer)
- Both the asker and the answerer enter the chat
- Afterward, the answer is accepted

(Does not apply if the asker and answerer are the same person.)

Perhaps award it multiple times?  Or have different levels of it?

The awarding of the badge might even come with a handy reminder:

> Nice work!  Thanks for taking the extra time to help a Stack Overflow user who was struggling.  Even though the answer has been accepted, don't forget to move any updates from the comments into the body of the answer to make it more complete and helpful for future visitors.  Thanks again!

Comment: Doesn't this mean the ultimate answer was buried in chat somewhere? I don't think we'd want to encourage that.

Comment: Hmm... that is an interesting idea, and I do like encouraging using chat rather than long comment threads, but I think I'm with @NickCraver here; that would probably encourage people to take things to chat. We don't really want to encourage/reward that; it's simply the lesser of two evils.

Comment: @NickCraver: That's possible, which is the main point of the reminder at the end.  Which still happens in day-to-day answering, so what I'm looking to encourage is A) Taking the time to reach that conclusion; and B) Reminding the user to finalize the answer.  Sometimes the ultimate answer is in the comments, sometimes in the chat, sometimes the comments are just to help the asker understand the answer.

Comment: I agree with Nick. But then the way you solve that problem is by posting the solution arrived at in chat *as an answer*. And you can already get badges and reputation for good answers.

Comment: "Does not apply if the asker and answerer are the same person"... what? you mean if he chats with himself, that doesn't count?

Comment: @Old What? No [Schizophrenic] badge?

Comment: Fewer comments and more chat use sounds like something sorely needed. Throw in a stronger way to encourage writing it up at the end and I'm sold.

Comment: Possibly includes a "answerer edits answer" step in there?  It's crude, but....

Comment: Wouldn't this reward people for teaching new users that it's good to post poorly-defined problems as questions on SO because the community will hold their hand and spend lots of time establishing what the actual question is?

Comment: Quite complicated to understand, and you must additionally implement it

Comment: @Flexo: That's the target, really.  These are all good points though, and I'm seeing the downsides.  In general it strongly feels like there's an opportunity to encourage acceptable use of the "move this to chat" feature to arrive at a helpful answer, the ultimate goal being to provide help to the asker.  I'm trying to think of a way to adjust this to focus more on that...

Comment: A badge may be a bit much.  Possibly increase the rep gain of an accepted question by 5 or so if the functionality was used prior?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If a "chat" session is required to answer a question properly, the question should not have remained open for answering during that time. It should have been put on hold pending clarification. *Not* being able to get an answer is the incentive we use for OP's to come back and actually fix their half baked questions. Also those providing answers should all be doing so from the same initial starting point. Having data from a chat transcript or not should not make the difference between an informed and an uninformed answer. That data needs to be in the question. We already incentivise editing (maybe not enough).

If a question/answer set was just an excuse for finding people to chat about a problem with, we'd never get any quality questions or answers. **I don't think we want to add incentives to take the business of answering questions outside the framework of answers.**

Even if you were to take this one step farther and also add incentive for the answer to get written up from chat into an answer, that still promotes a workflow that we're trying to avoid here. It will also open up a whole new world of abuses as people try to get people into chat first rather than just answering their question.